Trissur Siva Lingam Sthala Puranam and rituals
Is he covered with ghee throughout the year? What's the reason? Which Puranas mention about the Trissur Kshetram? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadakkunnathan_Temple

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Mahadeva I have heard that in that temple he is covered with ghee throughout the year and it is given as Prasadham. I want to know why.

can you add more details, like where is that temple and who is Trissur Kshetram? then the question will be ok. Lots of people can benefit, including me.

@Mahadeva https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadakkunnathan_Temple

that is very good, but it should be in the question, not as a comment click this link and add this info there, and all is good
